# Render google maps with backbonejs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, backbone-views

I'm learning backbone and I started to build an application that uses google maps. My problem is that when I try to render google maps in my view nothing happens, only appears the `div` that contains `id="map_canvas"` in gray, like this:

[image]

and in my console log I have this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined`

Code of my view:

```
ev.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({

    map: null,
    pos: null,

    initialize: function(){
        this.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('home'));
        this.render();
    },

    initMap: function(){

        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                //guarda a posicao currente do utilizador
                this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: this.map,
                    position: this.pos
                });
                console.log("a minha posicao eh: " + this.pos);
                this.map.setCenter(this.pos);
             });    
         }

         var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$el.find('#map_canvas')[0],mapOptions);
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this.initMap();
        return this;
    }
});
```

main.js:

```
var ev = new Application();

ev.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // Caching the Welcome View
        this.homeView = new ev.views.Home();
    },

    home: function () {
        $('#home').html(this.homeView.el);

    }
});

$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // Load HTML templates for the app
    ev.templateLoader.load(['shell', 'home'], function () {
        ev.shell = new ev.views.Shell({el: "#shell"});
        ev.router = new ev.Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
});
```

Comment: I did not get the logic behind initMap function. Why are you initializing map at the end? It looks like when you call initMap function, the condition gets true, as navigator will have gelocation in most of modern web browsers; so it directly goes inside the condition and tries to set the centre (this.map.setCenter) but it does not find the "this.map" .

Comment: I created that function to initialize the map, and if I remove the code inside of `if(navigator)` show's me the map with latitude and longitude that I define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this I haven't tested:

```
initMap: function(){
 this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$el.find('#map_canvas')[0],mapOptions);
 var that = this;  
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            //guarda a posicao currente do utilizador
            that.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: that.map,
                position: that.pos
            });
            console.log("a minha posicao eh: " + this.pos);
            this.map.setCenter(this.pos);
         });    
     }

     var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };

},
```

Comment: It's work with some modifications :), but essential of the response is `var that = this;`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, I hope it will work; I've not tested it.

```
initMap: function(){
        var that= this;
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$el.find('#map_canvas')[0],mapOptions);

        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                //NOTE : the scope of 'this' changes to the current function so use the fair copy of it as 'that'
                that.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: that.map,
                    position: that.pos
                });
                console.log("a minha posicao eh: " + that.pos);
                that.map.setCenter(that.pos);
             });    
         }
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: If it is still giving the same error then there is something wrong with the following things.
1) Probably, google map js is not loaded properly
2) this.$el.find('#map_canvas')[0] is producing something wrong due to which "this.map" remains undefined.